# How to set a cookie on add to cart and remove it when cart is empty?

Tags: magento-1.9, cookie

As in title - I'd like to set a cookie when any product is added to the cart and remove it if cart is empty.

I found a somewhat similar answer for [setting cookies on login](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/215038), which is perfect, cause I'd like to do that as well, but have no clue how to set equivalent for chart items (I'm new to Magento).

version  1.9.2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the event `controller_front_send_response_before` in the frontend area, check if there are items in cart (using the `checkout/cart` helper) and set or delete cookie. A possible function for that observer could be the following:

```
public function setCartDataCookie($observer)
{
    $cookieName = "YOUR_COOKIE_NAME";
    $cookie = Mage::getSingleton("core/cookie");
    $cookieData = $cookie->get($cookieName);

    $cart = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getItemsQty();

    if ($cart > 0){
        //set cookie, when items are in cart
        $cookie->set($cookieName,"YOUR DATA");
    } else {
        //cart is empty -> remove cookie
        if ($cookieData){
            $cookie->delete($cookieName);
        }
    }
}
```

If you need data about the cart items in the cookie you may use `Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems()` to get that information.